# Where can I get a standalone nmake.exe?

Tags: visual-studio, nmake

`nmake.exe`, a Microsoft Windows port of make, used to be available for [download](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q132084) at the Microsoft knowledge base servers. They've since taken the article down, and I don't know where I can reliably get a standalone version of `nmake.exe`. I would use a copy from one of the Microsoft Visual Studio development platforms, but I worry that I'll be forgetting to include some spare DLL file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original download page and file are stored on Web Archive

http://web.archive.org/web/20120402130733/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/132084

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20061013183052/http://download.microsoft.com/download/vc15/Patch/1.52/W95/EN-US/Nmake15.exe

Answer (score 20):

I am pretty sure you can't. It's included with Visual Studio these days. You'll find it in the `vc/bin` subdirectory. Its only non-standard dependency is the DLL version of the CRT, like `msvcrt90.dll` for the `nmake.exe` version included with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 5):

There is opensource clone of nmake:
https://wiki.qt.io/Jom#Download_the_binary_package
[image]

Comment: Nice to know! But I guess it's *very* likely to be only vaguely compatible with NMAKE (and which version of it? didn't find it mentioned). It has practically zero chance to support all of NMAKE's features, nuances and quirks a bigger build system is likely to grow some vines around. So, for one, instead of a "clone", I'd actually expect an "inspired by" approximation.